# How can I deploy to production webpack+Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, webpack

I want to deploy my project in production, but I can find information how to do it, I follow this information to created my website: [rails+webpack](https://medium.com/@hpux/rails-5-1-loves-javascript-a1d84d5318b), and just say for heroku but I am not using heroku.

I will really appreciate if you can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be understanding what Heroku is, you can easily use Heroku to deploy your website by following the steps mentioned in the same guide you posted. Using the command `git push heroku master` will deploy your application to a unique Heroku address which you can open by using `heroku open` in the CLI.

So first you'll need to create a **[Heroku account](https://signup.heroku.com/)** and then download the [**Heroku CLI**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) which is just an interface to use Heroku from the command line. And **[here's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5)** a great guide on how to deploy a Rails 5 application to Heroku, Heroku might seem a bit scary at first for beginners but it really is very simple.

Comment: I'm using a virtual machine (Digital Ocean), and I am not using heroku because it is for my developer company tests, any Idea how to do it or example by any chance.

Comment: Digital Ocean has a very easy way of deploying applications with their One-Click-Apps. Login to DigitalOcean and enter the Control Panel, click Create New Droplet, select the $5 server, a region and any other options you'd like then change to the One-Click-App tab and choose the Ruby-On-Rails on 16.04 and just follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean) guide to set the server up.